# AFTNetworking com Token para baixar imagem

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-request, http-headers

Estou testando o AFTNetworking para baixar imagens de um backend, porém estou tendo erros ao baixar imagens.

Testei diversas implementações, com esta implementação apresenta erro de conteúdo não aceito.

Abaixo está a ultima implementação que fiz de teste:

```
NSString* urlImagem = @"http://lojacliente.goldarkapi.com/pizzas/54bf3e3a657f6f2c04a81afd/imagem";

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

operationManager.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];

operationManager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
operationManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];


[operationManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"image/jpeg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[operationManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"zRWGVZ0HEpSzsb1ZOYMYHCwL6q54qa2x3y3JlNmCN61d1SCmfRDfnbFHteu/R50N29bOQJv8IgG6aLD4y8dNWQ==" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Api-Token"];

[operationManager GET:urlImagem parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"success");

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"failure. Error:%@",error);

}];
```

ERRO:

> GDRequestImageAFTNetworking[1647:65915] failure. Error:Error
>   Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request
>   failed: unacceptable content-type: image/jpeg" UserInfo=0x78604030
>   {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL:
>   http://lojacliente.goldarkapi.com/pizzas/54bf3e3a657f6f2c04a81afd/imagem
>   } { status code: 200, headers {
>       "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = "true, true";
>       "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "Content-Type, Content-Length, Depth, User-Agent, X-Requested-With, X-Requested-By,
>   If-Modified-Since, X-Access-Token, X-FileEncoding, Cache-Control";
>       "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD";
>       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
>       Connection = "keep-alive";
>       "Content-Length" = 25553;
>       "Content-Type" = "image/jpeg";
>       Date = "Fri, 30 Jan 2015 16:49:36 GMT";
>       Etag = "\"5c08b1f8fc6e9943027d4062badbd5d60aca31f0\"";
>       Server = "nginx/1.4.1 (Ubuntu)"; } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://lojacliente.goldarkapi.com/pizzas/54bf3e3a657f6f2c04a81afd/imagem,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type:
>   image/jpeg, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=

Como poderia estabelecer corretamente a configuração do cabeçalho da requisição com o Token?

Comment: O que acontece quando você remove o `content-type` da requisição?

Comment: Tiago, se após aplicar as sugestões para correção da sua pergunta ocorreu outro erro, não havia necessidade de alterar toda a sua pergunta, fazendo com que a resposta do *André* ficasse sem coerência. Você poderia apenas ter acrescentado a informação do novo erro na pergunta.

Comment: Sim desculpa. Não foi intensional. @AndréRibeiro, obrigado, sua resposta me ajudou a refinar o resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui realizar o download usando o seguinte código:

```
     AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

        operationManager.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];

        [operationManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"TOKEN" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Api-Token"];

        [operationManager GET:urlImagem parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

// responseObject será um valor do tipo UIImage, dispensando qualquer conversão de data 
// para image. Podendo ser usado diretamente ou inserido em um UIImage.

            NSLog(@"success");


        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"failure. Error:%@",error);

        }];
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você está enviando os *headers* HTTP através dos parâmetros do GET.

Para setar esses *headers* você deve usar o método [`setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPRequestSerializer.html#//api/name/setValue%3AforHTTPHeaderField%3A) da [`AFHTTPRequestSerializer`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPRequestSerializer.html)

Você pode fazer assim:

```
[operationManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"image/jpg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[operationManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"_TOKEN_" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Api-Token"];
```

Comment: Questão atualizada.

Comment: Eu já avia tentado usar o setValue:forHTTPHeaderField, mas também não funcionou... fiz algumas alterações e consegui. Era alguns parametros que coloquei que eram desnecessários.